# How can I increase the size of a CGRect by a certain percent value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cgrect

How can I increase the size of a CGRect by a certain percent value? Should I use some form of `CGRectInset` to do it?

Example:

Assume I have a CGRect: `{10, 10, 110, 110}`

I want to increase its size (retaining the same center point) by 20% to:

`{0, 0, 120, 120}`

Comment: for 2017, it's `insetBy`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use `CGRectInset` if you like:

```
double pct = 0.2;
CGRect newRect = CGRectInset(oldRect, -CGRectGetWidth(oldRect)*pct/2, -CGRectGetHeight(oldRect)*pct/2);
```

To decrease the size, remove the `-`s.

**Side note**: A `CGRect` that is 20% bigger than `{10, 10, 100, 100}` is `{0, 0, 120, 120}`.

---

**Edit**: If the intention is to increase by area, then this'll do it (even for rectangles that aren't square):

```
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(oldRect);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(oldRect);
double pct = 1.2; // 20% increase
double newWidth = sqrt(width * width * pct);
double newHeight = sqrt(height * height * pct);
CGRect newRect = CGRectInset(oldRect, (width-newWidth)/2, (height-newHeight)/2);
```

Comment: Re the sidenote: I think remus is correct that (110,110) gives an area 20% bigger than (100,100).

Comment: I suppose it depends on your interpretation of "20% bigger". By area, the resulting square has edges of length `109.5445`, which isn't as pretty as just assuming he meant to increase the edge size by 20%.

Comment: I meant increase edge sizes, but you're right, area would be an entirely different calculation, and this is a good answer.

Comment: Good thing I included both. :)

Comment: Selected as answer because ^

Comment: this is **insetBy** in the latest Swift, cheers @IanMacDonald

Answer (score 12):

In Swift:

```
func increaseRect(rect: CGRect, byPercentage percentage: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
    let startWidth = CGRectGetWidth(rect)
    let startHeight = CGRectGetHeight(rect)
    let adjustmentWidth = (startWidth * percentage) / 2.0
    let adjustmentHeight = (startHeight * percentage) / 2.0
    return CGRectInset(rect, -adjustmentWidth, -adjustmentHeight)
}

let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)
let adjusted = increaseRect(rect, byPercentage: 0.1)
// -0.5, -0.5, 11, 11
```

In ObjC:

```
- (CGRect)increaseRect:(CGRect)rect byPercentage:(CGFloat)percentage
{
    CGFloat startWidth = CGRectGetWidth(rect);
    CGFloat startHeight = CGRectGetHeight(rect);
    CGFloat adjustmentWidth = (startWidth * percentage) / 2.0;
    CGFloat adjustmentHeight = (startHeight * percentage) / 2.0;
    return CGRectInset(rect, -adjustmentWidth, -adjustmentHeight);
}

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,10,10);
CGRect adjusted = [self increaseRect:rect byPercentage:0.1];
// -0.5, -0.5, 11, 11
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C. Best to give answers in the desired language.

Comment: +1 for being the only answerer so far to have obeyed Apple's statement that _"your applications should avoid directly reading and writing the data stored in the CGRect data structure. Instead, use the functions described here to manipulate rectangles and to retrieve their characteristics."_ — https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html

Comment: Apple's statement is silly. I updated my answer to conform to it anyways. :/

Comment: Close second, and I actually like this answer too since it's got both Objc and Swift ;)

Comment: Looking at this one again, shouldn't the output rect be -1, -1, 11, 11?

Answer (score 6):

Sure, using `CGRectInset` works:

```
CGRect someRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
someRect = CGRectInset(someRect, someRect.size.width * -0.2, someRect.size.height * -0.2);
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4 extension inspired by several of the answers here with simplified calculations:

```
extension CGRect {
    func scaleLinear(amount: Double) -> CGRect {
        guard amount != 1.0, amount > 0.0 else { return self }
        let ratio = ((1.0 - amount) / 2.0).cgFloat
        return insetBy(dx: width * ratio, dy: height * ratio)
    }

    func scaleArea(amount: Double) -> CGRect {
        return scaleLinear(percent: sqrt(amount))
    }

    func scaleLinear(percent: Double) -> CGRect {
        return scaleLinear(amount: percent / 100)
    }

    func scaleArea(percent: Double) -> CGRect {
        return scaleArea(amount: percent / 100)
    }
}
```

Usage is simply:

```
rect.scaleLinear(percent: 120.0)  OR (amount: 1.2)
rect.scaleArea(percent: 120.0)  OR (amount: 1.2)
```

If you are interested in trying my testing methods:

```
/// Testing
extension CGRect {
    var area: CGFloat { return width * height }
    var center: CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: origin.x + width/2, y: origin.y + height/2)
    }

    func compare(_ r: CGRect) {
        let centered = center.x == r.center.x && center.y == r.center.y
        print("linear = \(r.width / width), area = \(r.area / area) centered \(centered)")
    }

    static func ScaleTest() {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 17, y: 24, width: 200, height: 100)
        let percent = 122.6
        rect.compare(rect.scaleLinear(percent: percent))
        rect.compare(rect.scaleArea(percent: percent))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using CGRect > insetBy in my Swift code

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454218-insetby

With this, your percent value will be the `scaleX` as my example.

```
    let dx = rectWidth*scaleX
    let dy = rectHeight*scaleX
    let rectangle = CGRect(x: rectX,
                           y: rectY,
                           width: rectWidth,
                           height: rectHeight).insetBy(dx: -dx, dy: -dy)
```

- use positive value to scale down
- use negative value to scale up

Answer (score 2):

Using Swift you can retain the center point (relative to the source Rect) and increase/decrease the size as follows using an extension:

```
extension CGRect {
    func centerAndAdjustPercentage(percentage p: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
        let x = self.origin.x
        let y = self.origin.y
        let w = self.width
        let h = self.height

        let newW = w * p
        let newH = h * p
        let newX = (w - newW) / 2
        let newY = (h - newH) / 2

        return CGRect(x: newX, y: newY, width: newW, height: newH)
    }
}
let newRect = oldRect.centerAndAdjustPercentage(percentage: 0.25)
```

Comment: CGRect extension is convenient, but this code does not work correctly. newX and newY should be added to the origin (x, y).  let newX = x + (w - newW) / 2

Answer (score 0):

```
let scale = percent / 100
let newRect = oldRect.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
```

<del>Beware that this approach also will change x and y of rectangle.</del>

Comment: This does not appear to scale relative to the center of the rectangle, thus does not change the x,y origin.

Comment: As the above comment states, this doesn't keep the center point of the rect!